# ChangeNotifier was used after being disposed

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

I am new to Flutter and stuck with this
I have a page that uses a class named GoogleMapsNotifier with ChangeNotifier and when I pop the page I want to dispose the Stream inside this class (last function).

```
class GoogleMapsNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  final geolocatorService = GeolocatorService();
  final placesService = PlacesService();
  final markerService = MarkerService();

  Position? currentLocation;
  List<PlaceSearch> searchResults = [];
  StreamController<Place> selectedLocation = BehaviorSubject<Place>();
  StreamController<LatLngBounds> bounds = BehaviorSubject<LatLngBounds>();
  late Place selectedLocationStatic;
  List<Marker> markers = <Marker>[];

  GoogleMapsNotifier() {
    setCurrentLocation();
  }

  setCurrentLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await geolocatorService.determinePosition();
    selectedLocationStatic = Place(
        geometry: Geometry(
          location: Location(
              lat: currentLocation!.latitude, lng: currentLocation!.longitude),
        ),
        name: '',
        vicinity: '');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  searchPlaces(String searchTerm) async {
    searchResults = await placesService.getAutocomplete(searchTerm);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  setSelectedLocation(String placeId) async {
    var sLocation = await placesService.getPlace(placeId);
    selectedLocation.add(sLocation);
    selectedLocationStatic = sLocation;
    searchResults = [];
    markers = [];
    var newMarker = markerService.createMarkerFromPlace(sLocation);
    markers.add(newMarker);
    var _bounds = markerService.bounds(Set<Marker>.of(markers));
    bounds.add(_bounds as LatLngBounds);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    selectedLocation.close();

    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

and then I have a Go Back button that pops the page and I call this function with Provider before.

```
onTap: () async {
                    Provider.of<GoogleMapsNotifier>(context, listen: false)
                        .dispose();
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
```

It works fine for the first time but when I enter the page for the second time and press Go Back button again, it return an error

> Unhandled Exception: A GoogleMapsNotifier was used after being
> disposed. E/flutter (13173): Once you have called dispose() on a
> GoogleMapsNotifier, it can no longer be used.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Provider` should be inside the `Route` you push. If you use a global provider, the instance of `GoogleMapsNotifier` will always be the same. Therefore the second time you go on the page it won't work (since it's the same instance you already disposed the first time)

Here is a concrete example

```dart
// GOOD
runApp(MaterialApp(...));

...

Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => ChangeNotifierProvider<GoogleMapsNotifier>(
      create: (_) => GoogleMapsNotifier(),
      child: ...,
    ),
  ),
);


// BAD
runApp(
  ChangeNotifierProvider<GoogleMapsNotifier>(
    create: (_) => GoogleMapsNotifier(),
    child: MaterialApp(
      home: ...,
    ),
  )
);

...

Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => ...,
  ),
);
```

Comment: ok, if I construct my MaterialPageRoute like this to go to this page its not showing the error but now do I access this provider now? before I was just declaring it as a final
final googleMapsNotifier =
        Provider.of<GoogleMapsNotifier>(context);

Comment: Well you can still access it with Provider.of<GoogleMapsNotifier>(context) when you are in the right Route can't you?

Comment: the problem is that there are no any errors now but looks like notifylisteners() does not work. I can print all the requests from the screen to the `GoogleMapsNotifier  with ChangeNotifier` class but nothing returns to the page. If I come back to the previous MaterialPageRoute builder - it works fine. Any ideas

Comment: If you want your change notifier updates to rebuild the UI you have to use ChangeNotifierProvider. I updated my answer.